# How to find and add css class to one of div's children?

Tags: events, angular, parent, target

```
<div class="post-content-container">
  <div class="post-content">
    Some very long text
  </div>
  <button (click)="showMore($event)">Show more</button>
</div>

<div class="post-content-container">
  <div class="post-content">
    Some very long text
  </div>
  <button (click)="showMore($event)">Show more</button>
</div>

<div class="post-content-container">
  <div class="post-content">
    Some very long text
  </div>
  <button (click)="showMore($event)">Show more</button>
</div>
```

I'd like to add a class to `post-content` after click on button. Well, firstly I need to find a parent, right? Then, I'd like to find one of it's children and add to it custom css class.

```
showMore(event: any) {
  let parent = event.target.parentNode; <-- post-content-container
  //now, how to get into parent's child (I mean post-content) and add to it some custom css class?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Angular2 right? There is no need to do any custom JavaScript like you would in jQuery. Here is how to add the class "myClass" by toggling the "showMyClass" value in your component, where the "showMyClass" property is a boolean. Or make "showMyClass" an array of booleans. Here is a full working example:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <div class="post-content-container">
        <div class="post-content" [ngClass]="{myClass: showMyClass[0]}">
        Some very long text 1
        {{showMyClass[0]}}
        </div>
        <button (click)="showMore(0, $event)">Show more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="post-content-container">
        <div class="post-content" [ngClass]="{myClass: showMyClass[1]}">
        Some very long text 2
        {{showMyClass[1]}}
        </div>
        <button (click)="showMore(1, $event)">Show more</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
    public showMyClass: Array<boolean>;

    constructor(){
      this.showMyClass = [];
    }

    showMore(index, event: any) {
      this.showMyClass[index] = !this.showMyClass[index];
    }
 }


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Well, maybe my post wasn't clear. There can be a couple of post-content-container with post-content divs and I don't want to add that class to all of them. I want to add that class only there where the button has been clicked.

Comment: I've updated my answer with your updated requirements :-) It's using an array of booleans for the "showMyClass" instead of a single property. Not the finest implementation but it works, you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. You have me nice idea. I did it a little different but also with indexes usage.